# How can I use computers with RJ-11 ports in an Ethernet network?

Tags: networking, cluster

In my school are many really old computers with Pentium 3 processors and Windows 95. I'd like to make a cluster of them.

Those computers have RJ-11 ports, not RJ-45 and I don't know if I can use an Ethernet cable switcher — I can't find an RJ-11 switcher anywhere!

How can I connect them?

Comment: RJ11 is a modem socket, not ethernet.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/642004/make-a-cluster-with-many-old-computers?noredirect=1#comment803735_642004

Comment: Are they desktops or laptops?

Comment: What do you actually expect from that "cluster"? Do you want to perform some distributed computations? Do you have any experience with such systems or some idea on implementing it? Distributed systems aren't "plug and play". Don't expect entire thing to work just like one big desktop computer too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to connect them to an Ethernet network, you'll need to get Ethernet adapters for them.